# What does an italic title of a Wikipedia article indicate?

Tags: wikipedia

The titles of most Wikipedia articles aren't italic ([example article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git)). But some are ([example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Solar_Probe)).

Making the title of a Wikipedia article italic isn't trivial and there is a [special Wikipedia article about how the make a Wikipedia article's title italic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Italic_title) but I wasn't able to find out why some Wikipedia articles' titles are italic. So why are they? What does it indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template is used to help facilitate the [Wikipedia Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Titles#Italics), which lists a lot of different circumstances where Italics need to be used.

Also found on the [guidance on Article titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Article_titles#Italics_and_other_formatting):

> Use italics when italics would be used in running text; for example, taxonomic names, the names of ships, the titles of books, films, and other creative works, and foreign phrases are italicized both in ordinary text and in article titles.